# Kill previously run jobs (that are waiting for human input) upon initiation of new one

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow

My question is simple.

Say i have a jenkins workflow job that is checking out some code, building a SNAPSHOT, all the way to performing automated testing and deploying it for QA.

After this I have a "manual input" that serves as a pause to the workflow in order to ask whether or not to proceed with releasing the code. Let's call this `run1`.

Now say that QA finds a bug and needs to get a new SNAPSHOT for testing. This would invoke a new build (`run2`) and a new manual question.

If QA goes to `run1` and proceeds with releasing then that would mean that i've released the wrong code.

I'd like to kill all previously running jobs when i start the new one. Is this possible through groovy script/workflow command? Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone struggling with the same problem, I had to use a workaround to get to it.

I used the RESTful API to force 'Abort' any previous job running by cycling through each (i only keep 10 jobs before i discard them so it's fairly quick)

http://udaypal.com/workflow-integration-using-rest-api/

It's hacky but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Easier option is to use timeout:

```
stage 'approve'
timeout(time: 7, unit: 'DAYS') {
input message: 'Do you want to deploy?', submitter: 'ops'
}
```

Comment: What happens if before the given expiry time a new job wants to spawn?

Comment: Couple of things:  1. I would expect that when QA finds the bug, they are the ones that goto the pipeline and say "No".  2. Set your timeout to a lower value. 3. When QA finds a bug, this should be replicated in an automated test that fails the pipeline in the testing stage from then on out.